# правильная инициализация и использование экземпляров map динамически (бор)

Tags: c++, map

Пытаюсь сделать дерево бор с весами слов. не пойму, что происходит - кажется, что обрабатываются совсем не те экземпляры `leaf_t` на которые ссылаюсь, сделал `dump` дерева, сразу увидел, что в `node_t` лежат частично не те экземпляры `leaf_t`,  что еще более непонятно. По разному извращался с ссылками, [так](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cddc0b6b83fc3d6e) ничего не вышло

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

typedef std::map<char,int>  leaf_t;
typedef struct{
    size_t id;
    leaf_t leaf;
    float weight;
} node_t;

class bor{
    std::vector<node_t> nodes;
public:
    bor(){
        nodes.push_back(node_t{0,leaf_t{},0});
    };
    void add_word(std::string word,float weight){
        std::cout<<"add_word "<<word<<std::endl;
        node_t& branch=std::ref(nodes.at(0));
        for(size_t i=0;i<word.size();i++){
            char c=word[i];
            leaf_t& leaf=ref(branch.leaf);
            std::cout<<"\tnode id:"<<branch.id<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"\t\tleaves("<<leaf.size()<<") "; for(auto& [x,y]:leaf) {std::cout<<"["<<x<<","<<y<<"] ";} std::cout<<"leaf["<<c<<"]="<<leaf[c]<<std::endl;
            if (!leaf[c]){
                size_t last=nodes.size();
                nodes.push_back(node_t{last,leaf_t{},0});
                leaf[c]=last;
                std::cout<<"\t\tadd leaf="<<c<<" node="<<last<<std::endl;
                std::cout<<"\t\tadd leaves("<<leaf.size()<<") "; for(auto& [x,y]:leaf) {std::cout<<"["<<x<<","<<y<<"] ";} std::cout<<std::endl;
            }
            branch=std::ref(nodes.at(leaf[c]));
        }
        std::cout<<"\tnode id:"<<branch.id<<std::endl<<"\t\tset weight:"<<weight<<std::endl;
        branch.weight=weight;
    };
    void print(std::string prefix="",size_t index=0){
        if (!index) std::cout<<"print"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"prefix \'"<<prefix<<"\'"<<std::endl;
        if (nodes.at(index).weight>0) std::cout<<prefix<<":"<<nodes.at(index).weight<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"nodes"<<std::endl;
        for(auto& [p,i]:nodes.at(index).leaf){
            std::cout<<"leaf"<<index<<std::endl;
            if (i) print(prefix+p,i);
        }
    };
    void dump(){
        std::cout<<"dump"<<std::endl;
        for(size_t i=0;i<nodes.size();i++){
            std::cout<<"node id:"<<nodes.at(i).id<<" s:"<<nodes.at(i).leaf.size()<<" w:"<<nodes.at(i).weight<<std::endl;
            for(auto& [a,b]:nodes.at(i).leaf) std::cout<<"["<<a<<","<<b<<"]"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    bor dict;

    dict.add_word("aa",0.01);
    dict.dump();
    /*dict.add_word("aas",0.1);
    dict.dump();
    dict.add_word("ad",1);
    dict.dump();
    dict.add_word("add",10);
    dict.dump();
    dict.add_word("asd",100);
    dict.dump();*/

    dict.print();
}
```

вывод

```
add_word aa
    node id:0
        leaves(0) leaf[a]=0
        add leaf=a node=1
        add leaves(1) [a,1] 
    node id:1
        leaves(0) leaf[a]=0
        add leaf=a node=2
        add leaves(1) [a,2] 
    node id:2
        set weight:0.01
dump
node id:0 s:1 w:0
[a,0]
node id:1 s:0 w:0
node id:2 s:0 w:0
print
prefix ''
nodes
leaf0

Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я посмотрел на код и у меня складывается ощущение, что его писало два человека. Один - студент 1 курса и второй - член комитета по стандартизации с++.

К примеру, есть такой код

```
for(auto& [x,y]:leaf) {
  std::cout<<"["<<x<<","<<y<<"] ";
}
```

этот код повторяется как минимум 4 раза (три из них практически идентичны).

С одной стороны используется фича с 17 стандарта, которую поддерживает только gcc 7.1. Clang не поддерживает. С другой стороны сам вывод написан в стиле древних плюсов.

Поэтому, лучше, как минимум, сделать отдельную функцию

```
void print_leaf(const leaf_t& leaf) {
  for (const auto& l : leaf) {
    std::cout << "[" << l.first << "," << l.second << "] ";
  }
}
```

и заменить в нужных местах. Теперь оно будет компилироваться любым адекватным компилятором с поддержкой 11 стандарта.

Но ещё лучше, написать правильный оператор вывода.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const leaf_t& leaf)
{
  for (const auto& l : leaf) {
    os << "[" << l.first << "," << l.second << "] ";
  }
  return os;
}
```

и тогда можно писать просто

```
std::cout << leaf;
```

Плюс такого способа - унификация вызовов и возможность не только на экран вывести, а и в файл.

Все это была присказка, потому что я хотел скомпилить код.

Теперь о ошибке. Все знают, что `std::vector` (далее просто вектор) - это очень удобная и простая штука для замены классических массивов. И почти всегда вектор может мимикрировать под массив. Но мало кто задумывается, а что происходит, когда внутрь вектора добавляется новый элемент (например, вызовов `push_back`).

В вектора кроме размера есть ещё "вместимость" (capacity). Вместимость всегда либо больше, либо равна размеру. Если при вставке нового элемента в конец вместимость больше размера, то вектор просто увеличит размер на единицу и скопирует элемент в правильное место. Остальные элементы **останутся на своих местах**.

Если же в векторе не хватает места, то вектор выделит место в другом месте с запасом (чудная тавтология) и скопирует туда элементы. Все элементы **переехали на новое место**. По старым адресам их нет.

Что это все значит? а то, что если мы каким то образом сохранили указатель/ссылку на какой-то элемент вектора, то после `push_back` указатель может "неожиданно" стать невалидным. Это все описано в стандарте в районе 23.3.6.5
 `[vector.modifiers]`.

Ближе к коду.

вначале берется ссылка на элемент вектора

```
node_t& branch=std::ref(nodes.at(0));
```

или так

```
branch = std::ref(nodes.at(leaf[c]));
```

Потом, внутри цикла по этой ссылке дергается ещё одна ссылка

```
leaf_t& leaf=ref(branch.leaf);
```

пока вектор не меняется, все хорошо. Все ссылки валидные.

Но дальше, неожиданно может произойти такое

```
nodes.push_back(node_t {last,leaf_t{},0});
```

и после этой строки все может пойти на перекосяк прямо в следующей строке

leaf[c]=last;

так как leaf может указывать в дремучие леса.

А падает оно - где повезет. Потому что память уже побита. У меня падало в декструкторе класса `bor` при попытке удалить этот самый вектор.

Самый простой способ пофиксить (жуткий костыль, но пофиксить) - запретить вектору делать перелокацию. Для этого я в конструктор добавил одну строку

```
bor() {
    nodes.reserve(10000);
    nodes.push_back(node_t {0,leaf_t{},0});
};
```

Но будет ли работать все правильно? а кто его знает. Но valgrind теперь молчит как партизан.

По хорошему, там нужно правильно переписать код, о котором я говорил выше. Но как это сделать - это уже нужно хорошо разобраться в алгоритме.

Как защитить себя от подобного и предовращать такие баги ещё на подлете? Компилировать в gcc с параметром `-fsanitize=address`. Теперь, когда приложение будет работать, в случае ошибок в консоль будет вываливаться красивое разноцветное:)

Comment: спасибо огромное, не догадался посмотреть vector::push_back. [Тут](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/549bb62c4621b075) исправленный код, заменил vector на list, а индексы на reference_wrapper